# Squid is not asking for User Name and Password when using NCSA

Tags: windows-server-2008, squid

I am using squid proxy on Windows machine (Win2K8 Server, 64 bit). I referred [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-squid-proxy-server-authentication.html) link to enable NCSA authentication. The installation goes well and I am able to start the service but still I am unable to get Username and Password prompt.

Below is my squid configuration. Please note that I removed all the commented lines from original squid configuration file to reduce the size of post (Due to Stack's character limitation).

```
#   WELCOME TO SQUID 2.7.STABLE8
#   ----------------------------
#

    auth_param basic program c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth.exe c:/squid/etc/passwd
    auth_param basic children 5
    auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
    auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
    auth_param basic casesensitive off
#
#Recommended minimum configuration:
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32
#
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet

http_access deny all

icp_access allow localnet
icp_access deny all
# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?


#Default:
 cache_mem 8 MB

access_log c:/squid/var/logs/access.log squid

# none

#Suggested default:
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320


coredump_dir c:/squid/var/cache
```

I have generated the passwd file using [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator-windows/)
Please help. I am trying to get this work since last week :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your rules:

```
http_access allow ncsa_users
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet

http_access deny all
```

I see you are allowing both the ncsa_users, and the localnet.
If you are accessing this from inside the 10.0 network (don't see in description), you are allowing all traffic without any auth from it with this rule:
`acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network`
So try commenting that one out and see if it works.